# Get json value using regex in linux bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression, json

I have a json file **file.json** like this:

```
{
  "abc": "123",
  "def": 456,
  "ghi": 789
}
```

I am trying to get value of all the keys using regex in bash terminal.

Here is what I tried for getting value of **abc**:

```
var=cat file.json
regex='(abc\":) \"(.+)\",'
[[ $var =~ $regex ]]
echo ${BASE_REMATCH[1]}
```

It doesn't print anything. I am trying to get/print value of **abc** i.e. **"123"**

Please note that I can't use jq because it is not available to use on the machine where I need it and I can't install it either.

Comment: *I can't install it either* - can I ask, what distro and how old is it?

Comment: If you are asking in a professional capacity, then I would propose that you jump through the necessary hoops to get `jq` installed on your production system.  It is unreasonable to be expected to perform one's job using the wrong tools, and parsing JSON in a shell script using `awk` or other text-processing tools that are not JSON-aware is simply not a cost effective way to do your job in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file really is as simple as you show (without any special JSON encoding in the string values), I would just use `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1=="\"abc\":"{print $2}' file | tr -d '",'
123
```

Or even GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '"abc":\s*"?\K[^,]+' file | tr -d '",'
123
```

The `-P` enables PCRE regular expressions which give us `\K` for "ignore everything matched up to this point". Using `\K` with the `-o` option ("print only matched portion of the line") lets us use something to find the right match and then discard it so it isn't included in the output. So here, we are looking for the string `"abc":`, then 0 or more whitespace characters (`\s*`) followed by 0 or one quote (`"?`), we discard everything up to here, and then look for the longest stretch of non-`"` characters (`[^"]+`).

Finally, the `tr` will delete any `"` or `,` characters to leave you with the unquoted value.

Comment: what does K do in 2nd solution? and what changes would be required to 2nd solution if I need value of 'def' and 'ghi', it has numeric value unlike 'abc'.

Comment: $ grep -oP '"abc":\s*"\K\d+' file 
This seems to work fine for getting numeric values.

Comment: @mmk see updated answer. You don't need to change anything to get numeric values, and in fact the `\d` will fail for things like `1.5`. Use the exact same thing no matter what the values are because it is just looking for non-`"`, so that includes numbers and everything else.

Comment: Terdon, well for numeric value, it has ',' too in the end.

Comment: @mmk ah, I see, numbers aren't quoted. Right, see updated answer. This one should work for both scenarios.

Comment: do we really need `tr -d '",'`, maybe we can just add 'OR' operator for `"` and `,`? `grep -oP '"release":\s*"\K[^"|,]+' version_info.json`? what do you think?

Comment: @mmk the `tr` is there to remove the `"` and `,` if you don't want to remove them, don't use the `tr`.

Answer (score 4):

You'd need something like:

```
var=$(cat file.json) || exit
regex='"abc"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"((\\.|[^"\\])*)"'
if [[ $var =~ $regex ]]; then
  value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  printf '%s\n' "$value"
fi
```

But even then, you'd need to decode the json string to get the actual value. For instance, `foo\"\nbar` should be converted to `foo"<newline>bar` and `\u0031\u0032\u0033` to `123`.

Best would be to use a proper json parser:

```
value=$(jq .abc < file.json)
```

```
value=$(PERL_UNICODE= json_xs -t none -e 'print $_->{abc}' < file.json)
```

```
value=$(perl -C -MJSON -0777 -ne 'print decode_json($_)->{abc}' file.json)
```

```
value=$(
  python3 -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["abc"])' < file.json
)
```

The problems in your approach were:

- syntax to get the output of a command is either `$(cmd)` or the deprecated `` `cmd` ``. `var=cat file.json` would try to run the `file.json` command with `var=cat` passed in its environment.
- `\"` in a regex doesn't mean anything. It would likely be considered the same as `"` but there's no guarantee.
- `.+` matches one or more characters as many as possible, so it would match over `"`s and newlines until the last `"` in the string. Here we replace it with a sequence of zero-or-more (`*` instead of `+`) of  either `\` followed by any single character or a character other than `\` or `"` so it runs until the next unescaped `"`.
- You have two capture groups in your regexps, the first one is what is matched by `(abc\":)`, while you obviously want the second one (the value).
- The variable is `$BASH_REMATCH`, not `$BASE_REMATCH`
- you can't use `echo` to output arbitrary data.
- in list contexts at least, parameter expansions must be quoted in bash.

Comment: you did read that `I can't use jq`?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I did not, no, sorry. But there are several alternatives to jq including python, perl or ruby.

Comment: @JaromandaX we answer questions not only for the person asking but also for everyone else who might come across a question and have a similar problem. This answer provides a way that does not require `jq` and then also gives the better approach for those who don't have the OP's limitation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas why `var=$(cat file)`? What's the benefit of loading the entire file into a variable instead of just parsing it?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas for some reason value is empty. I can see that it is going inside if flow, but ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} is empty, I am wondering what could be the reason

Comment: @mmk, it works with your sample, try adding a `typeset -p BASH_REMATCH` in the if statement to see what it contains. Maybe you modified the script and added more capture groups?

Comment: @terdon, I showed the OP how to modify their approach so it works.

Comment: Fair enough. Knowing you, I thought there might also be some obscure technical reason :)